# how to set custom click in notification android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

****When the app is on background the push notification  will come, I want to implement a click which navigate to  an another activity (Mainchat.class, I tried pending indent and all  but it still launches the splash activity****

This is the code to pass my intent when app is background

******MyFirebaseMessagingservice******

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.e(TAG, "MSSGTYPE: " + remoteMessage.getMessageType());


        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {


            if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("token")) {

                String Sender_name = remoteMessage.getData().get("sender");
                String messageBody = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
                String messageCount = remoteMessage.getData().get("messageCount");
                String senderId = remoteMessage.getData().get("senderId");
                String chatNotification = remoteMessage.getData().get("chatNotification");


                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", messageBody);
                pushNotification.putExtra("Sender_name", Sender_name);
                pushNotification.putExtra("messageCount ", messageCount);
                pushNotification.putExtra("senderId", senderId);
                pushNotification.putExtra("chatNotification", chatNotification);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
                pushNotification.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, pushNotification,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                intent.putExtra("message", remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, new Intent(this, NewNotification.class),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            }
        }
    }



private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
           //Commented by venkatesh

            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

        } else {
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification");
            handleDataMessage(message);
        }
    }



private void handleDataMessage(String message) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json message: " + message);
        String title = "getsummary";

        boolean isBackground = true;
        String imageUrl = "";
        String timestamp = "";


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray

//            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
//            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);
//
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainChat.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }

    }


    public String getAppLable(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = null;
        try {
            applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.getApplicationInfo().packageName, 0);
        } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return (String) (applicationInfo != null ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) : "Unknown");
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }
```

**This is my Nottificationuttils.clas**

```
public class NotificationUtils {

    private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext;

    public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        // Check for empty push message
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            return;


        // notification icon
        final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher1;

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);

        final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

            if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                } else {
                    showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                }
            }
        } else {
            showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            playNotificationSound();
        }
    }


    private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher1)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher1)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
     * the notification tray
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Playing notification sound
    public void playNotificationSound() {
        try {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method checks if the app is in background or not
     */
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        //If your app is the process in foreground, then it's not in running in background
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return true;
    }


    // Clears notification tray messages
    public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

It is not working when i click at the push notification it will launch the splash screen activity
help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

In firebase there are 2 types of messages mainly, i guess you are sending [notification msg](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications), as per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) if the app is in background when notification msg arrives, fcm shows the notification directly without triggering FirebaseMessagingService, and click of this notification it opens the default launcher activity specified in manifest file.
But if you want FirebaseMessagingService to always triggered, irrespective of the app in background or foreground, then use fcm [data msgs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) and when the message arrives show notification as you are doing now.

Comment: can uexplain wih aegxample

Comment: you only handling the backend for sending fcm notification?

Comment: RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON,"{ \"notification\": {\"title\": \""+User+"\", \"text\": \""+message+"\",\"